# Strange JAX-RS Mapping for not available resource

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy

we have some really strange behavior regarding JAX-RS @PATH mapping (using ReastEasy, Jackson 1.9).

Following scenario:

- We have a couple of LocalServices and CrudServices which have JaxRS annotations

For Example:

```
@Path('/')
public interface CarService extends AbstractService {

    @POST @Consumes(...) @Produces(...)
    @Path('/car/calculate')
    Value doSomething(Car car);
}


/* This class has no jax rs annotations at all */
public class CarImpl implements CarService {

    public void someMethodWithoutAnnotation(Currency ccy) { ... }

    public Value doSomething(Car car) { ... }        

}
```

Now, I execute the following request in a integration test:

```
POST url/carfoobar
```

Yes - exactly 'carfoobar'.

Instead of receiving a '405 - the specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.', I can see that:

- jackson dispatched the request to: PathInfo: /carfoobar
- we really have no resource with a path containing 'carfoobar'
- we have **no** method of a resource, which takes a path with a dynamic pathparam
- resteasy finds the 'CarImpl' class as the suitable Managed Bean for this request (CarImpl has no jaxrs annotations!)
- it throws an exception that it can't find a MessageBodyReader to map the incoming json into a Currency object (obviously, it tries to map the request onto CarService.someMethodWithoutAnnotation)

My question is:

Why is this happening? Why is resteasy trying to map a incoming rest request onto a method. In my opinion it should throw a exception, that no suitable path could be found.

Regards,

Comment: I don't know why RestEasy is doing some of those things as I've never used it, but, the reason why it's considering `CarImpl` at all must be that it implements `CarService` which is annotated with `@Path`.  Also your example is clearly incomplete, because `CarImpl` is missing an implementation for `doSomething` (is this in turn calling `someMethodWithoutAnnotation(..)`?) and you have a typo on `implements CarService()`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. Tried to get a minimal example and got some typos into it.

The CarImpl provides an implementation for the doSomething method, but it looks like the 'someMethodWithoutAnnotation(...)' is getting used for the not existing path @POST @Path('carfoobar') - thats the strange part.

Comment: First thing I would do is NOT use `@Path("/")` for a class. If this is being done with all your classes, it's possible you are expecting one class to get hit and actually another class is. The search will not go from class to class. The first one it sees fit will be the root resource class. Either use a `@Path` with a meaningful root resource name or use sub-resource locators

Comment: Secondly Jackson _does_ no dispatching. It is simply a marshaller/unmarshaller

Comment: _"obviously, it tries to map the request onto CarService.someMethodWithoutAnnotation"_ - What makes you say that? If there is a `MessageBodyWriter` (notice `Writer` not `Reader`) missing, then this method is not the problem. The problem is with an instance of `Currency ` being converted to JSON. What you are thinking is a a problem with JSON to `Currency` which is a `MesageBodyReader` problem.

Comment: For better help you should try to break down the example into the **minimal** test case, which you have tested and it produces the same result. Show how you configure your app, show how you attempt to consume the resource, a complete resource class. Anything you feel we would need to reproduce the problem(s). Personally I would start a simple app from scratch. That's just me. That how I would create an [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer - I really should tidy up the @Path('/') on the Classnames.
- got a type: it throws an Exception regarding MessageBodyReader not Writer -
The part which makes me think, that the 'someMethodWithoutAnnotation(Currency c)' is called is because I see the exception that it can not find a MessageBodyReader for Currency. And the 'someMethodWithoutAnnotation' is the only method in that context which makes use of an input parameter of the type Currency.

Answer (score 1):

Your CarService interface is annotated with `@Path('/')`. Jackson correctly dispatches the implementation of the CarService interface, which is CarImpl. It there looks for a method that has `@POST @Path("carfoobar")`, which is not found and throws an exception for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, Jackson dispatches the CarImpl because of the interface, but then it doesn't throw an exception because it can't find a method for @POST @Path('carfoobar'). It throws an exception, that it is not able to serialize 'Currency', which looks like it maps the request to the 'someMethodWithoutAnnotation' method - thats the strange part.

Comment: Sorry. I cannot reproduce that.